# Upsert KV pair in subdocument for specific rules

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How to update a document and insert key-value in subdocument for specific rules?

> MongoDB version: 3.4

Use this CLI to insert simulation data

```
db.country.insertMany([{"_id":"us","groups":[{"group":"1"},{"group":"2"} ]},{"_id":"eu","groups":[{"group":"1"},{"group":"2"}]}, {"_id":"jp","groups":[{"group":"2"}]}])
```

original data

```
db.country.find()

{
    "_id": "us", "groups": [ { "group" : "1" }, { "group": "2" } ]
}
{
    "_id": "eu", "groups": [ { "group" : "1" }, { "group" : "2" } ]
}
{
    "_id": "jp", "groups": [ { "group" : "2" } ]
}
```

How to get this result? ( just add status: happy to group 1 )

```
{
    "_id": "us", "groups": [ { "group" : "1",  "status": "happy" }, { "group": "2" } ]
}
{
    "_id": "eu", "groups": [ { "group" : "1", "status": "happy" }, { "group" : "2" } ]
}
{
    "_id": "jp", "groups": [ { "group" : "2" } ]
}
```

---

I know how to select all groups that match group=1

```
db.country.aggregate([ 
    {'$unwind': '$groups'},  
    {'$match': {'groups.group': '1'}} , 
    {'$project': {'group': '$groups.group', _id:0 }}  
])

{ "group" : "1" }
{ "group" : "1" }
```

and also know how to use `update + $set` like this

```
// { "_id": 1, "people": {"name": "tony" } }
db.test.update({_id: 1}, { $set: {'people.country': 'taiwan'}})
// { "_id": 1, "people": {"name": "tony" , "country": "taiwan" } }
```

but how to merge `update + $set` and `aggregate function`? Please help me.

pymongo is OK for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get this result? ( just add status: happy to group 1 )

Use `$` to refer the position of the matched sub-document in array.

```
db.coll.update_many({'groups.group':'1'}, {'$set': {'groups.$.status': 'happy'}})
```

see more [here](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

Comment: It seems that it still the simple $set issue, thanks